# Wintermute iOS App Gets "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, simulator

I am currently attempting to port a game I've developed in the Wintermute Lite engine to iOS platforms.  My game will compile just fine in XCode (albeit using the armv6 architecture) and will run perfectly on the iOS simulator; however, when I try to deploy it to an iPad, the first thread will halt in XCode with the error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, adress=0xfffffff6)", pointing to a non-specific line of assembly code.

First of all, if you guys have any ideas right off the bat as to what might be causing this, I would greatly appreciate some help.  The thing is, I'm more than willing to debug this myself, but being a complete noob with Objective-C as well as XCode, I'm not sure how to trace this specific error back to the line of code that's causing it (I apologize if this is a really basic question but I've already attempted to find a command to get the line of code associated with the error, but with no success).

I realize that this is scant on details, but as I said, I'm not sure how to pinpoint the piece of code that's causing this error using XCode, otherwise I'd just debug this myself.  If there's any extra information I can provide, let me know.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Check Console. You should be able to see when the app crashed and more specific information about what caused the crash.

Comment: Did you add an exception breakpoint?  If not this page will tell you how:  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode4UserGuide/060-Debug_Your_App/debug_app.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH3-SW1 (under "Add an exception breakpoint")

Answer (score 1):

I got it working.  After a lot of messing around with XCode, I realized that I incorrectly configured the project file provided by Wintermute.  As far as I can tell, it had something to do with the fact that the project was originally set to build for "iOS Universal" and I changed it to "iPad 5.0," which somehow caused the project to break upon deployment.

Anyway, I started over with a new XCode project file and got it to compile perfectly!  Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the fact that it isnt ment to run on iOS. The reason it runs on he simulator is that it is building for a Intel chip set, not ARM. **Even** though you set it to armv6 it doesn't mean that the code will *run* on a non-intel device.

Comment: Their website says that there is experimental support for iOS.